# Truncate and casting to int of ceiled double

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding, truncation

When performing a `std::ceil` on a double value the value will round up to a whole number. So 3.3 will become 4.0. Which can be casted or truncated to an `int`. Which will 'chop off' the part after the comma. So:

```
int foo = (int)std::ceil(3.3);
```

So at first glance this will store 4 in foo. However, the double is a floating point value. So it might either be `4.000000001` or `3.999999999`. The latter would be truncated to 3.

But in practice I've never seen this behaviour occurring. Can I safely assume that any implementation will return 4? Or is it only the `IEEE-754` that does this. Or have I just been lucky?

Comment: “However, the double is a floating point value. So it might either be 4.000000001 or 3.999999999. ” No, it's 4. Really.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: It's easy to forget that "relatively small integers" are guarenteeded to be stored with no loss. I just did! Your short note reminded me about that. Please expand it a little and make it an answer.

Comment: Similar related question, but not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029443/does-ieee-754-float-double-and-quad-guarantee-exact-representation-of-2-1

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I did not know about this guarantee:). But does that mean the truncation might 'fail' for int sizes larger than the mantissa? After all the mantissa of a double might be smaller than an int a long.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rounding (or ceil-ing) a double will always, always, always be exact.

For floating point numbers below 2^(m+1), where m is the number of mantissal bits, all integers have exact representations, so the result can be exactly represented.

For floating point numbers above 2^(m+1)... they're already integers. Makes sense, if you think about it: there aren't enough mantissal bits to stretch down to the right of the decimal point. So again rounding/ceil-ing is exact.

Answer (score 0):

`ceil` in C++ behaves like it does in C, where the standard says

> [The ceil functions compute the smallest integer value not less than x.](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1256.html#7.12.9.1)

The result of `ceil` is always the floating-point representation of an integer; however, the result may overflow an integral type when truncated.

In your particular case, `std::ceil(3.3)` *must* be exactly `4.0`, since that's the "smallest integer value not less than" `3.3`.

Comment: What do you mean by "The result is always an integer"? The result of the ceil function? And how is an integer stored in a double different from a non integer?

Comment: @laurisvr Yes. Added some clarification.

Comment: Ah now I understand what you mean:). However that does not answer my original question. Since the integer value is still stored in a double

Comment: @laurisvr I can't see how it doesn't answer your question, but added some further clarification.